# hide a relative layout when user clicks outside it, Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with two relative layouts. In one of them I have three buttons and it width is set to wrap_content. I want to be bale to hide this layout when the user clicks on any area that is outside this layout.

How can I do this

Comment: Can't you set an `OnClickListener` on the other `RelativeLayout` to do it ?

Comment: tried this but it will only work on the places where there is no element in the other LAyout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the OnTouchEvent() inside your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchPointX = event.getX();
    float touchPointY = event.getY();
    int[] coordinates = new int[2];
    layoutToHide.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);
    if(touchPointX < coordinates[0] || touchPointX > coordinates[0] + layoutToHide.getWidth() || touchPointY < coordinates[1] || touchPointY > coordinates[1] + layoutToHide.getHeight())
    layoutToHide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) // or View.GONE if you want more space.
```

P.S. I haven't tested this code and be sure to know the difference between `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.GONE` so you can figure out which one is the appropriate choice for you.

Comment: should i set it for the other layout ? just like onclick listeners ?

Comment: Place the code inside the `Activity` that holds both fragment and replace `layoutToHide` with the reference to the layout(s) you want to hide.